Lightnovel where the main character kills people to keep his wife safe
I remember the male main character killing the wife's nanny who is currently her maid whom she trusted and he is misunderstood. Later it's proven that he did it because she tried to poison the wife. This is similar to other events where the main character kills people to keep his wife safe. He is misunderstood and killed by his wife. Later his wife finds out the truth of why the main character did it. She arranges a ball and kills everyone who helped frame him, then kills herself. She regresses as well to the time when the main character regressed to.

Does this have any fantasy or SF elements?

"regresses to a time"  ... does this indicate some kind of time travel/ time reversal? Or reincarnation in a different era?  Isekai, perhaps ?

"Regression" is a common term used for reincarnation into a previous time.
